# Parse MultiLevel Json using U-SQL

Tags: u-sql

After parsing below JSON using u-sql I want to save it in CSV -
id,type,name,ppu,battername,batterid,battertype,toppingDate,toppingid,toppingtype.

My code works from id till ppu fields but not beyond that.

Sample Json-
 `{
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {"battername":"NA",
                "batter":
                    {
                        { "batterid": "1001", "battertype": "Regular" },
                        { "batterid": "1002", "battertype": "Chocolate" },
                        { "batterid": "1003", "battertype": "Blueberry" },
                        { "batterid": "1004", "battertype": "Devil's Food" }
                    }
            },
        "topping":
            [{
                "toppingDate": "2018-11-30T10:00:01",
                "toppingValues": [
                { "toppingid": "5001", "toppingtype": "None" },
                { "toppingid": "5002", "toppingtype": "Glazed" },
                { "toppingid": "5005", "toppingtype": "Sugar" },
                { "toppingid": "5007", "toppingtype": "Powdered Sugar" },
                { "toppingid": "5006", "toppingtype": "Chocolate with" },
                { "toppingid": "5003", "toppingtype": "Chocolate" },
                { "toppingid": "5004", "toppingtype": "Maple" }
            ]}
    }`

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];
USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;
DECLARE EXTERNAL @InputPath string = @"input.json"; 
DECLARE EXTERNAL @OutputPath string = @"output.csv";
@commonCookedInput =
EXTRACT id string,
        type string,
        name string,
        ppu int?,
        battername string,
        batterid int?,
        battertype string
FROM @InputPath
USING new MultiLevelJsonExtractor( "batters.id",
                                   "batters.type",
                                   "batters.name",
                                   "batters.ppu",
                                   "batters.battername",
                                   "batters.batterid", 
                                   "batters.battertype"
                                  );
OUTPUT @commonCookedInput
TO @OutputPath
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting: false,outputHeader:true);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? please post your u-sql code

Comment: @Peter Added the code.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But, this is not even a valid json input.